# Inaccessible member function when trying to overload << stream as friend?

Tags: c++, friend

---

Problem Solved, thank you all for your help!

---

I've run into a problem that i can't seem to figure out.

I am trying to overload the ostream operator as a friend function in order to be able to print out the member data of that object, and i can't seem to get it to work.

This is what i got so far:

.h file:

```
Class TestIt:
{
public:
TestIt();
TestIt(int a, b);

friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const TestIt& a);

Private:
int NUMBER1;
int NUMBER2;
};
```

.cpp file:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const TestIt& a)
{
 outputStream << a.NUMBER1 << " " << a.NUMBER2;

return(outputStream);
}
```

What i am trying to do is, pass in an object in ostream, then output its member data.
The error that i am receiving is that

"the member TestIt::NUMBER1 declared in TestIt.h is inaccessible.

and same error also exists with my other member data.

Why would that be?

Thank you for your help.

---

Here's a whole program that i just wrote, giving me the same error:

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

TestClass::TestClass(int a, int b)
{
    age = a;
    whole = b;
}

int TestClass::GetAge() const
{
    return(age);
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const TestClass& t1)
{
    t1.whole;
    t1.age;

    return(outputStream);
}
```

TestClass.h

```
#ifndef TestClass_H
#define TestClass_H

class TestClass
{

public:
    TestClass(int a, int b);
    int GetAge() const;

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const TestClass& t1);

private:
    int whole;
    int age;

#endif
```

Comment: How about posting the code you're actually having trouble with? Or creating an example that exhibits the problem *and* compiles? After fixing the syntax errors in your snippet it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Sure, I've added a whole program that gives me that error.

Comment: Either a typo or an issue in the real code: There is a missing `};` in the `TestClass` definition.

Comment: And your program [compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/dlZWw) successfully (after I added the missing `};` at the end of the `TestClass` definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<<` that you've defined and the `operator<<` that you've friended aren't the same name.  Are you using namespaces?

Comment: Yes, i have 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
in both .cpp file and in my driver.cpp file.

Comment: You were right, i didn't have "using namespace" in my header file which gave me huge lists of errors.

Comment: Don't put `using namespace X` in your header file (preferably don't put it anywhere.